# Как переформатировать стандартный почтовый адрес с помощью регулярного выражения (пример внутри)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть список почтовый адресов, при клике на которые я получаю полный адрес. В полном адресе мне нужно сделать сокращение: во всех местах где идет **название улицы и само слово "улица"** на **ул. Название улицы**. Например чтобы при клике адрес был не

> Россия, Оренбургская область, Соль-Илецк, Садовая улица, 21

а

> Россия, Оренбургская область, Соль-Илецк, ул. Садовая, 21

```js
$('li').click(function(){
 console.log($(this).data('text'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown nano-content" tabindex="0" style="right: -17px;">
  <li data-text="Россия, Оренбургская область, Соль-Илецк, Садовая улица, 21">
    <h3>Садовая улица, 21</h3>
    <p>Россия, Оренбургская область, Соль-Илецк</p>
  </li>
  <li data-text="Россия, Оренбургская область, Бугуруслан, Садовая улица, 21">
    <h3>Садовая улица, 21</h3>
    <p>Россия, Оренбургская область, Бугуруслан</p>
  </li>
  <li data-text="Россия, Оренбургская область, Адамовский район, посёлок Адамовка, Садовая улица, 21">
    <h3>Садовая улица, 21</h3>
    <p>Россия, Оренбургская область, Адамовский район, посёлок Адамовка</p>
  </li>
  <li data-text="Россия, Оренбургская область, городской округ Новотроицк, село Хабарное, посёлок Родник, Садовая улица, 21">
    <h3>Садовая улица, 21</h3>
    <p>Россия, Оренбургская область, городской округ Новотроицк, село Хабарное, посёлок Родник</p>
  </li>
  <li data-text="Россия, Оренбургская область, Асекеевский район, сельское поселение Мартыновский сельсовет, посёлок при станции Филипповка, Садовая улица, 21">
    <h3>Садовая улица, 21</h3>
    <p>Россия, Оренбургская область, Асекеевский район, сельское поселение Мартыновский сельсовет, посёлок при станции Филипповка</p>
  </li>
  <li data-text="Россия, Оренбургская область, Октябрьский район, село Октябрьское, Садовая улица, 21">
    <h3>Садовая улица, 21</h3>
    <p>Россия, Оренбургская область, Октябрьский район, село Октябрьское</p>
  </li>
  <li data-text="Россия, Оренбургская область, Домбаровский район, поселок городского типа Домбаровский, Садовая улица, 21">
    <h3>Садовая улица, 21</h3>
    <p>Россия, Оренбургская область, Домбаровский район, поселок городского типа Домбаровский</p>
  </li>
  <li data-text="Россия, Оренбургская область, Кувандык, Садовая улица, 21">
    <h3>Садовая улица, 21</h3>
    <p>Россия, Оренбургская область, Кувандык</p>
  </li>
  <li data-text="Россия, Оренбургская область, Асекеевский район, сельское поселение Троицкий сельсовет, село Троицкое, Садовая улица, 21">
    <h3>Садовая улица, 21</h3>
    <p>Россия, Оренбургская область, Асекеевский район, сельское поселение Троицкий сельсовет, село Троицкое</p>
  </li>
  <li data-text="Россия, Оренбургская область, Медногорск, Садовая улица, 21">
    <h3>Садовая улица, 21</h3>
    <p>Россия, Оренбургская область, Медногорск</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Лучше не надо. https://habr.com/company/hflabs/blog/417235/

Comment: @Qwertiy, так вроде в статье ничего не говорите про СЕО или типа того, просто про формы и неудобства которые могут возникнуть из-за удобств

Comment: @Qwertiy мне нужно для заполнения объектов недвижимости для внутреннего пользования, длинный и понятный адрес занимает очень много места на выходе. Хотелось бы сократить но при этом получить привычный вид

Comment: @Qwertiy а насчет полностью ручного ввода я позаботился)

Comment: ```'Россия, Оренбургская область, Асекеевский район, сельское поселение Троицкий сельсовет, село Троицкое, Садовая улица, 21'.replace(/([^,]+)\s+?(?:улица)/ig, ' ул.$1')```